# How to resolve the NS_ERROR_FILE_TOO_BIG error in a POST request in PHP?

Tags: php, return, http-post

I have this error when making a request via POST in PHP. NS_ERROR_FILE_TOO_BIG
Attached image.

I couldn't identify where the problem is.
I noticed that when there are few records to be returned it works, the problem happens when there are more than 100 records.[image]

The returned array is created in a `foreach` . I noticed that when there are less than 100 records to interact with, `foreach` works. The error occurs when there are more than 100 records.

Comment: How large is the actual file? Ignore the lines, look at the file size.

Comment: Hi aynber, I'm not sending any. I hope I understood your comment correctly. I just make this request: return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url_base + "url",
            date:{
                'idLei' : $('#idLei').val(),
                'action': action,
                'idSubject': idSubject,
                'idAreaDeAtuacao' : idAreaDeAtuacao,
                'idTask': idTask
            },

Comment: I'd suggest trying another browser. If this is Firefox, it might have to do with possibly the browser cache. It doesn't look like it's really even attempting the connection

Comment: This is certainly not a PHP problem, and it also seems unlikely to be caused by a web server response. You are seemingly using JavaScript to process the upload via XMLHttpRequest. Make sure your JavaScript code is not manipulating the file before the submission. Other suspects could be some browser extension or your antivirus.